# Mouse-pressed event is fired but mouse-moved event is not

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I'm using Qt3D. I'm adding [QObjectPicker](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qobjectpicker.html) to my 3D entities like this:

```cpp
Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker *MyScene::createObjectPickerForEntity(Qt3DCore::QEntity *entity)
{
    if (!entity)
        return nullptr;

    picker = new Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker(entity);
    picker->setHoverEnabled(true); // I set this correctly
    picker->setDragEnabled(true); // Also required!
    picker->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("__internal ") + entity->objectName());
    entity->addComponent(picker);
    connect(picker, &Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::pressed, this, &MyScene::handlePickerPress);
    connect(picker, &Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::moved, this, &MyScene::handlePickerMove);

    return picker;
}
```

The **mouse press** events are fired, and corresponding slot logs the name of pressed entity and global coordinate **correctly**:

```cpp
void MyScene::handlePickerPress(Qt3DRender::QPickEvent *event)
{
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *pressedEntity = qobject_cast<Qt3DCore::QEntity *>(sender()->parent());
    if (!pressedEntity && !pressedEntity->isEnabled())
        return;

    qDebug() << "Pressed Entity Name: "<< pressedEntity->objectName();
    qDebug() << "Global Coord: " << event->worldIntersection();
}
```

However, to my surprise, the **mouse move** (hover) events are **not working**. The following slot function is NOT logging anything. Also, when I place a debugger break-point at this slot, I see that it is NOT invoked at all:

```cpp
void MyScene::handlePickerMove(Qt3DRender::QPickEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Hover Intersection:" << event->worldIntersection();
}
```

Am I missing something?

---

My Qt3D rendering settings are:

```cpp
m_renderSettings = new Qt3DRender::QRenderSettings();
m_renderSettings->pickingSettings()->setPickMethod(Qt3DRender::QPickingSettings::TrianglePicking);
m_renderSettings->pickingSettings()->setPickResultMode(Qt3DRender::QPickingSettings::NearestPick);
m_renderSettings->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("__internal Scene frame graph"));
m_renderer = new Qt3DExtras::QForwardRenderer();
m_renderer->setClearColor(QColor("#c8c8c8"));
m_renderSettings->setActiveFrameGraph(m_renderer);
m_renderSettings->setRenderPolicy(Qt3DRender::QRenderSettings::RenderPolicy::OnDemand);

m_rootEntity->addComponent(m_renderSettings);

m_rootEntity->addComponent(new Qt3DInput::QInputSettings());
```

### UPDATE

Relates to [this report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-78294).

Comment: Don't know if this is relevant, but did you enable `mouseTracking`? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#details

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Thanks =) I guess that option applies more to GUI widgets and `QWidget` class. I'll do more research on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of the `moved` signal [says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qobjectpicker.html#moved): "This signal is emitted when the bounding volume defined by the pickAttribute property intersects with a ray on a mouse move **with a button pressed**".

So this signal is not emitted on hover/mouse move, but on mouse move while pressing a mouse button.

Comment: Also, as far as I checked, `Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::entered` and `Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::exited` signals only fire while left mouse button is kept pressed.